# JDBI leaking threads

Tags: java, sqlite, kotlin, memory-leaks, jdbi

Even though I see the SQLite table is being populated, the test fails due to a thread leak.
The problem started happening when I introduced writing to SQLite table using JDBI.
Is there a known thread leak issue with JDBI? How would I debug it further?

([This](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/test-framework/src/java/org/apache/lucene/tests/util/LuceneTestCase.java#L254) annotation in base test class is looking for and reporting about thread leaks. )

```
import org.apache.lucene.util.LuceneTestCase
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Test
import org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi
import org.jdbi.v3.core.kotlin.KotlinPlugin
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlite3.SQLitePlugin
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.SqlObjectPlugin
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.kotlin.KotlinSqlObjectPlugin
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager

class MyTest: LuceneTestCase() {
    @Test
    fun testDatawrite() {
        
        val rawdata = MyData(id=1, name="stackoverflow")
        val jdbi = Jdbi.create(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/world.db"))
        jdbi.installPlugin(SQLitePlugin())
        jdbi.installPlugin(KotlinPlugin())
        jdbi.installPlugin(SqlObjectPlugin())
        jdbi.installPlugin(KotlinSqlObjectPlugin())

        jdbi.withExtension<Unit, MyDao, Exception> (
            MyDao::class.java)
            {
                dao ->
                dao.insert(listOf(rawdata))

            }
    }
}
```

Error message

```
1 thread leaked from SUITE scope at MyTest: 
   1) Thread[id=26, name=ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19, state=WAITING, group=TGRP-MyTest]
        at java.base@11.0.11/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1628)
        at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakError: 1 thread leaked from SUITE scope at MyTest: 
   1) Thread[id=26, name=ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19, state=WAITING, group=TGRP-MyTest]
        at java.base@11.0.11/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1628)
        at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
    at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([63412597]:0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is JDBI and not Sqlite related? Can you reproduce that with another database (e.g. h2 or hsqldb)? That would be really helpful.

From what I can see is that this is a JDK cleaner thread and that might be unrelated to both JDBI and sqllite.